# Did any tennis tournaments retain Rebound Ace after the Australian Open switched to Plexicushion?

Tags: equipment, tennis, atp, wta

From 1988 to 2007, the Australian Open used [Rebound Ace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebound_Ace) surfaces. In mid-2007, the tournament organisers decided that from 2008, the tournament would instead be played on [Plexicushion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plexicushion) surfaces. From memory, the lead up tournaments in Hobart and Sydney formerly used Rebound Ace but subsequently changed to Plexicushion following the Australian Open's lead.

Were there any tournaments on either ATP, WTA or second-tier tours that retained Rebound Ace as a surface after the Australian Open's change? If so, are there any that continue to use Rebound Ace now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to hard courts there are lots of different names for the surface when you get specific. Some indoor hard court surfaces are known as "Premier Court" for example, and as far as outdoor hard courts go, in addition to the general name of "Outdoor Hard Court" there are more specific names such as "Plexicushion", "Cushion Plus", "DecoTurf" (US Open uses this) or "Plexipave" (which is the surface at Indian Wells).

To answer your question - I believe the year-end WTA Championships in Istanbul, Turkey still use the Rebound Ace surface. That is the only current professional tournament I'm aware of that still uses it, though. DecoTurf seems to have become the preferred surface for many professional tournaments because of the speed it plays at and the bounce it gives is favored by many players. Back when the Australian Open used Rebound Ace there were some complaints from players that the surface got too hot and sticky and they didn't like the way it played.